# Disable sign up option using Clerk authentication?

Tags: authentication, clerk

I'm using Clerk to implement authentication for my application. It's an app that will only be used internally so I just want the people I give access to be able to sign in. I don't really want anyone to have the ability to sign up themselves. I like Clerk for how easy it is to add auth to apps but I'm not seeing a way to disable the sign up feature. Has anyone tried this?

Comment: I reached out to Clerk directly, as well as asked the same question in their Discord. Seems the only way to achieve this is to create a custom sign in form. I'll be doing this in the upcoming days, will let you know if it is possible.

Comment: Also interested in this, as I only need auth for a select few pre-defined admins.

Comment: @Phobos hi Phobos, can you provide an update if you were able to succesfully keep your clerk singup disabled?

Comment: @op_exchanger I was able to remove the sign up hyperlink by overriding the css on the form, as to whether or not it is still accessible I don't know - I'll have to have a look the next time I'm developing the app.

Comment: One additional change I made was setting my sign-up URL environment variable to where my sign-in page is, as an extra precaution:

NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL=/sign-in
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_URL=/sign-in

Answer (score 9):

In this case I'm using ***Nextjs***, navigate to _app.tsx file inside src/app/pages folder

```js
import { ClerkProvider } from "@clerk/nextjs";


const MyApp: AppType = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
return (
  <ClerkProvider appearance={{
        elements: {
          footer: "hidden",
        },
      }}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </ClerkProvider>
)}
```

So in this scenario, if you want users to not be able to signup...you can simply disable the signup text below which says "Don't have an account? **Signup**" by modifying the whole element with css . The css class of the signup text is - footer, which you can edit in your own way. for more, read the doc: https://clerk.com/docs/users/build-your-own-ui

Comment: What's happening here, can you explain how your solution answers the question?

Comment: If you have experience in clerk then you might know about the clerk ui customization. Simply hide the sign up text below by adding the appearance attribute inside the signIn or maybe the main <ClerkProvider></clerkProvider> tag.

Comment: Thanks for response Melvin, I was asking as a part of review. If you want to clarify your answer please use the edit button so future visitors will understand your answer better. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can just enable the allowlist feature (which is a premium feature) but if you're in a development enviroment in clerk it should just allow you to enable the feature with a warning, and in the allowlist you can input your email so no-one except you can login into the app. I personally use this feature of clerk for my ecommerce projects' admin page!

Comment: exactly my use-case as well, cheers!

Comment: Hope I helped you out @PetrosKyriakou

Answer (score 2):

For future reference. If you are using CRA / Vite-React. you can format it like this:

```
  <Route path="/sign-in"  
   element={<SignIn  
         routing="path" 
          path="/sign-in" 
          appearance={{
            elements: {
              footerAction: { display: "none"  },
            },
           }}  />
```

[Sign in form look like this after removal:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSKIZ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Only Paid plan... not nice! Auth0 is the better choice for me here, more MAUs and SignUp restriction for free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only secure way to do that is using the allow list option in your Clerk dashboard.

Turning on the white list with out identifiers will give you the expected behavior.

[image]

https://clerk.com/docs/authentication/allowlist

The bad new is that you can't use it in production mode with the free plan

Answer (score -1):

in your .env create this

*NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL=/sign-in

NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=/(page to be redirected after login)*

Then Create a folder called sign-in, another folder in that one called [[...sign-in]] and add a file named page.jsx

page.jsx

```
import { SignIn } from '@clerk/nextjs';

const SignInPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
      <SignIn appearance={{
        elements: {
          footer: {
            display: 'none',
          },
        },
      }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignInPage;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).